# Is there a way to dump the whole postgres db using pg_dumpall from remote host by specifying certificates?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dumpall

I have a kubernetes cluster and I have configured a statefulset with two replicas (lets say postgres-0 and postgres-1), one will be active and another will be standby for a perticular time. Now I want to run pg_dumpall from postgres-1 to connect to postgres-0 by specifying certificates (which I already created).
I am able to dump a particular database using :

`pg_dump "port=5432 host=10.20.30.40 user=postgres dbname=test sslcert=pg.cert.pem sslkey=pg.key.pem sslrootcert=ca.crt sslmode=verify-ca" -f test.sql`

I need to do the same with pg_dumpall. Is there any to do that?
Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pg-dumpall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but you have to use the connect string as an argument to the `-d` option:

```sh
pg_dumpall -d 'host=... port=... ...' -f test.sql
```

Comment: And I to restore I am using pg_restore, there -d option represents db name. So what will be the option for connection string in this?

Comment: This is a plain text dump, and you restor it with `psql`. You can use the `-d` option to pass a connect string.